# How to get performance of mongodb cluster from logs using mongodb keyhole?

Tags: mongodb

I have installed Mongodb keyhole in my ubuntu server. Iam trying to analyze performance of a MongoDB cluster from the log file using the below command.

keyhole --loginfo log_file[.gz] [--collscan] [-v]

But the problem is iam getting the below error, eventhough the log file is same directory where iam running the command.Anyone please help me on this.

2022/10/12 11:20:45 open logfilename_mongodb.log.gz.[gz]: no such file or directory

I have fixed the issue with the below command format.

./keyhole -loginfo -v ~/Downloads/logfilepath.log

Comment: The `.gz.[gz]` looks pretty suspicious there

Answer (score 1):

Glancing at the [Logs Analytics](https://github.com/simagix/keyhole/blob/cc528a3811e769ba8674c55474799fb2e751cba2/loginfo.md#examples) readme for the project, it looks like you've got a simple syntax issue here. The `[]` characters are intending to indicate optional arguments/settings to use when running `keyhole`.

Have you tried a syntax similar to this?

```
keyhole --loginfo log_file --collscan -v
```

Comment: yes i tried, but getting the same error.

Comment: I see you edited the question with the solution, but it's not clear how the solution is meaningfully different than what was suggested here in this answer? If I understand correctly, the solution was to use proper command line arguments and path resolutions?

Comment: No, I got help directly from MongoDB support regarding that command, So i posted here, so that it will be usefull for anyone.

Comment: More info at https://www.simagix.com/2021/02/feel-pulse-of-mongo.html